# What updates mtime after writing to memory mapped files?

Tags: linux, mmap, memory-mapped-files, xfs

I'm using XFS on Linux and have a memory mapped file to which I write once per second.  I notice that the file mtime (shown by `watch ls --full-time`) changes periodically but irregularly.  The gap between mtimes seems to be between 2 and 20 seconds but it is not consistent.  There is very little else running on the system--in particular there's only one program of mine writing the file, plus one reading.

The same program writes much more frequently to some other mmapped files, and their mtime changes exactly once per 30 seconds.

I am not using `msync()` (which would update mtime when called).

My questions:

1. What updates mtime?
2. Is the update interval configurable?
3. Why do some mtimes get updated exactly once per 30 seconds but some files which I write less frequently have fresher (irregular but always less than 30 seconds old) mtimes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `mmap` a file, you're basically sharing memory directly between your process and the kernel's page cache — the same cache that holds file data that's been read from disk, or is waiting to be written to disk. A page in the page cache that's different from what's on disk (because it's been written to) is referred to as "dirty".

There is a kernel thread that scans for dirty pages and writes them back to disk, under the control of several parameters. One important one is `dirty_expire_centisecs`. If any of the pages for a file have been dirty for longer than `dirty_expire_centisecs` then all of the dirty pages for that file will get written out. The default value is 3000 centisecs (30 seconds).

Another set of variables is `dirty_writeback_centisecs`, `dirty_background_ratio`, and `dirty_ratio`. `dirty_writeback_centisecs` controls how often the kernel thread checks for dirty pages, and defaults to 500 (5 seconds). If the percentage of dirty pages (as a fraction of the memory available for caching) is less than `dirty_background_ratio` then nothing happens; if it's more than `dirty_background_ratio`, then the kernel will start writing some pages to disk. Finally, if the percentage of dirty pages exceeds `dirty_ratio`, then any processes attempting to write will block until the amount of dirty data decreases. This ensures that the amount of unwritten data can't increase without bound; eventually, processes producing data faster than the disk can write it will have to slow down to match the disk's pace.

The question of how the mtime gets updated is related to the question of how the kernel knows that a page is dirty in the first place. In the case of `mmap`, the answer is that the kernel sets the pages of the mapping to read-only. That doesn't mean that you can't write them, but it means that the first time you do, it triggers an exception in the memory-management unit, which is handled by the kernel. The exception handler does (at least) four things:

1. Marks the page as dirty, so that it will get written back.
2. Updates the file mtime.
3. Marks the page as read-write, so that the write can succeed.
4. Jumps back to the instruction in your program that writes to the `mmap`ed page, which succeeds this time.

So when you write data to a clean page, it causes an mtime update, but it also causes the page to become read-write, so that further writes don't cause an exception (or an mtime update)<sup>note 1</sup>. However, when the dirty page gets flushed to disk, it becomes clean, and also becomes "read-only" again, so that any further writes to it will trigger another eventual disk write, and also another mtime update.

So now, with a few assumptions, we can start to piece together the puzzle.

First, `dirty_background_ratio` and `dirty_ratio` are probably not coming into play. If the pace of your writes was fast enough to trigger background flushes, then most likely you would see the "irregular" behavior on all files.

Second, the difference between the "irregular" files and the "30 second" files is the page access pattern. I surmise that the "irregular" files are being written to in some sort of append-mode or circular-buffer fashion, such that you start writing to a new page every few seconds. Every time you dirty a previously untouched page, it triggers an mtime update. But for the files displaying the 30-second pattern, you only write to one page (perhaps they are one page or less in length). In that case, the mtime is updated on first write, and then not again until the file is flushed to disk by exceeding `dirty_expire_centisecs`, which is 30 seconds.

*Note 1:* This behavior is, technically, wrong. It's unpredictable, but the standards allow for some degree of unpredictability. But they do require that the mtime be sometime *at or after the last write* to a file, and at or before an `msync` (if any). In the case where a page is written to multiple times in the interval before it's flushed to disk, this isn't what happens — the mtime gets the timestamp of the *first* write. This has been discussed, but [a patch that would have fixed it](https://lwn.net/Articles/564120/) wasn't accepted. Therefore, when using `mmap`, mtimes can be in error. `dirty_expire_centisecs` sort of limits that error, but only partially, since other disk traffic might cause the flush to have to wait, extending the window for a write to bypass mtime even further.

Comment: FWIW, I've been using Linux for 18 years, read RML's book, and done some very lightweight kernel dev, but I'm not an expert, especially not when it comes to the mm, so I might have made some mistakes. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Wow this is a lot of useful information!  Thank you.  Your theory about different write patterns influencing the `mtime` behavior is interesting...but it's also a little confusing because the files that have erratic mtime steps are indeed written in an append-only fashion, but at a constant rate (one fixed-size record per second).  If it were like a text log file I could see why constantly appending would encounter a new page at irregular time intervals, but in my case the write rate is constant (for those particular files).  The files with consistent time steps are indeed smaller and random.

Comment: @JohnZwinck on thinking about this a little more, if your record size doesn't evenly divide the page size, then that would account for a +/- 1 second variability in the time between mtime updates, but I don't have any idea how to account for bigger differences than that :)